# Re-installed LyX on Windows 8 laptop; pdf preview doesn't work

Tags: lyx, miktex, windows

At first, LyX was popping up an error message (something to the effect that it couldn't find some sort of MiKTeX thing; I'm sorry I didn't write down the exact message).  Anyway, I was able to fix that problem:  I followed the instructions on [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55857#55857) (specifically, I used Method 2 under "MiKTeX GUI (Windows XP/Vista/7/8)") and installed all of the "installable packages" (there were lots).  [In case it matters, I had to chose a new package directory first.  Also, I didn't see the option to "Select Updatable Packages" and a few of the listed packages apparently weren't either "installable" or "uninstallable" (because neither the plus nor minus sign became activated when I selected those packages).]

Anyway, now when I try the pdf preview, I no longer receive an error message.  Instead, it says "Successful preview of format:  PDF (pdflatex)" in the bottom left-hand corner.  But no pdf shows up!  (I've tried a few different files, including LyX's "Introduction" file).

I have Adobe Reader 9 installed on my laptop (and no other pdf readers, to my knowledge).  I am certain I was using Adobe Reader with LyX the last time I had LyX installed (just a few months ago), and it worked fine then.  (Maybe I have allowed Adobe to install some updates since then, but I don't know).

One more note:  When I re-installed LyX, it did say that the package directory I had been using was not functioning (corrupted or something like that), so I had to use a new one.  I'm not sure if that could be causing an issue or not.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.